# How to to use .xib file migrated with the static library placed with .h files?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a static library which is having .xib file along with classes
I want to use that .xib file and further want to create the .framework from it b.
But the scene is that when I dragged the static library project I have access to all classes and its objects but not to the `ViewController.xib`
this is AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <StaticLibProject/ViewController.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property(strong , nonatomic) ViewController *viewControllerObject;


@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize viewControllerObject;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    viewControllerObject =[[ViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    viewControllerObject.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 567);

    [self.window addSubview:viewControllerObject.view];

    return YES;
}
```

And I am getting the following error

```
2015-02-05 13:43:00.255 AppsLibTest[1012:297168] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2C4BF742-2B3C-4978-957F-D99D8D54D422/AppsLibTest.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewController''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x183f9a59c 0x1946ac0e4 0x183f9a4dc 0x188b57448 0x188a5c274 0x18874c844 0x18874c7b0 0x10001d100 0x1887be00c 0x1889d4fd4 0x1889d7754 0x1889d5dec 0x18c21162c 0x183f52a28 0x183f51b30 0x183f4fd30 0x183e7d0a4 0x1887b73c8 0x1887b23c0 0x10001d5b8 0x194d1aa08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have bundled the xib file, you can try this:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[ViewController class]];
viewControllerObject = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:bundle];
```

if `bundle` is nil, then you need to check how you package your framework.

Comment: how iI can provide actual path of that .xib file. For the bundle??

Comment: @Rohit_RK you've got the NSBundle, you can use [NSBundle -pathForResource:ofType] to get the actual path.

Comment: I dont want to get the path want to provide it .

Comment: @Rohit_RK I don't understand what you mean

Comment: 'reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/45DB265C-8359-4468-AEE2-3094F6206343/LibraryTest.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewController'''

Comment: I am getting above reason for exception :- Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Comment: @Rohit_RK So are you sure you've bundled the xib in your static lib?

Comment: Yes It is there along with my header file in Include folder

Comment: @Rohit_RK in the include folder doesn't equal to in your product lib, you need to check you product bundle to see if the xib exist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70298/discussion-between-rohit-rk-and-carmelos).